# How can I aggregate the results of my SQL query?

Tags: sql, sum

I currently have the following query, which returns time sheet entries for a particular employee and month:

```
SELECT supervisors.employee, 
       hourscharged.project, 
       hourscharged.chargedescription, 
       hourscharged.account, 
       hourscharged.org, 
       hourscharged.entered_hrs 
FROM   accounting 
       INNER JOIN hourscharged 
               ON hourscharged.period_no_cd = accounting.period_no_cd 
       INNER JOIN supervisors 
               ON hourscharged.employeeid = supervisors.employeenumber 
WHERE  supervisors.employee = 'JOHN' 
       AND accounting.accountingmonth = 'FEB-13' 
GROUP  BY supervisors.employee, 
          hourscharged.project, 
          hourscharged.chargedescription, 
          hourscharged.account, 
          hourscharged.org, 
          hourscharged.entered_hrs
```

The query returns 7 rows with the following values for

```
Employee | Project | ChargeDescription | Account | Org | ENTERED_HRS:
JOHN | 15113 | MBT Upgrade | 0510 | 1.1.10.5 | 2.00
JOHN | 15113 | MBT Upgrade | 0510 | 1.1.10.5 | 3.50
JOHN | 15113 | MBT Upgrade | 0510 | 1.1.30.4 | 2.00
JOHN | 15113 | MBT Upgrade | 0510 | 1.1.30.4 | 3.50
JOHN | 34188 | KY13 S & T  | 0320 | 1.1.30.4 | 1.00
JOHN | 34188 | KY13 S & T  | 0320 | 1.1.30.4 | 4.00
JOHN | 34188 | KY13 S & T  | 0320 | 1.1.30.4 | 8.00
```

These are timesheet entries.  I want to show unique rows with totals for those rows, namely:

```
JOHN | 15113 | MBT Upgrade | 0510 | 1.1.10.5 | 5.50
JOHN | 15113 | MBT Upgrade | 0510 | 1.1.30.4 | 5.50
JOHN | 34188 | KY13 S & T  | 0320 | 1.1.30.4 | 13.00
```

I tried:

```
SELECT supervisors.employee, 
       hourscharged.project, 
       hourscharged.chargedescription, 
       hourscharged.account, 
       hourscharged.org, 
       Sum(hourscharged.entered_hrs) <-- * 
FROM   accounting 
       INNER JOIN hourscharged 
               ON hourscharged.period_no_cd = accounting.period_no_cd 
       INNER JOIN supervisors 
               ON hourscharged.employeeid = supervisors.employeenumber 
WHERE  supervisors.employee = 'JOHN' 
       AND accounting.accountingmonth = 'FEB-13' 
GROUP  BY supervisors.employee, 
          hourscharged.project, 
          hourscharged.chargedescription, 
          hourscharged.account, 
          hourscharged.org, 
          hourscharged.entered_hrs
```

and got:

```
JOHN | 15113 | MBT Upgrade | 0510 | 1.1.10.5 | 38.50
JOHN | 15113 | MBT Upgrade | 0510 | 1.1.30.4 | 38.50
JOHN | 34188 | KY13 S & T  | 0320 | 1.1.30.4 | 91.00
```

which was very strange because the following query (for example)

```
SELECT chargedescription, 
       Sum(entered_hrs) 
FROM   hourscharged 
WHERE  employeeid = '123456' 
       AND chargedescription LIKE 'KY13 S & T' 
GROUP  BY chargedescription
```

gave the correctly summed hours, namely:

```
JOHN | 34188 | KY13 S & T  | 0320 | 1.1.30.4 | 70.00
```

Can I do what I want with SUM?  If so, please guide me.  I have searched extensively on the application of the aggregate SUM function but I cannot seem to apply it to my own problem.  I also find it strange that using SUM over ENTERED_HRS in my complex query gives me summed hours that are entirely wrong.  If SUM won't work, what will?  I am failing to understand the principle that I need to apply.  The schema upon which this query is based may not be ideal but it is legacy and I need to work with it.  I am also using SQL Server 2005.  Thank you.

My query with `INNER JOIN` is equivalent to:

```
SELECT supervisors.employee, 
       hourscharged.project, 
       hourscharged.chargedescription, 
       hourscharged.account, 
       hourscharged.org, 
       hourscharged.entered_hrs 
FROM   supervisors, 
       accounting, 
       hourscharged 
WHERE  supervisors.employee = 'JOHN' 
       AND hourscharged.employeeid = supervisors.employeenumber 
       AND accounting.accountingmonth = 'FEB-13' 
       AND hourscharged.period_no_cd = accounting.period_no_cd 
GROUP  BY supervisors.employee, 
          hourscharged.project, 
          hourscharged.chargedescription, 
          hourscharged.account, 
          hourscharged.org, 
          hourscharged.entered_hrs
```

Answer (score 0):

The sum() function is working correctly.  It's the other fields you are selecting with it that are causing the problem.  Or it might be your data.

In these two lines:

JOHN | 15113 | MBT Upgrade | 0510 | 1.1.10.5 | 38.50

JOHN | 15113 | MBT Upgrade | 0510 | 1.1.30.4 | 38.50

There are different values for the HoursCharged.Org result.  You should look at what is causing that.